# Getting counts of records within bands

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of data which contains numbers from 0 to 100.

I would like to write a query that gets counts of records in the bands 0 to 10, 11 to 20 ......and 91 to 100

Is this possible?

Many thanks for any help.

Dave

Comment: What are the fields in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table looks something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `ts` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

...you could tackle this with a mathematical approach:

```
SELECT ROUND((T.ts-1)/10) AS "tt",
       COUNT(*)
FROM test1 AS T
GROUP BY tt;
```

Answer (score 0):

sub query would do the job for you

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(brands) FROM data_table where brands BETWEEN 1 and 10 ) as '1-10',
  ...
  (SELECT COUNT(brands) FROM data_table where brands BETWEEN 90 and 100 ) as '90-100',
```

Answer (score 0):

Select count from(
 Select * from (select * from table where val >= 'lowerlimit') where val<='upperlimit')

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the results:

```
SELECT MIN(`id`) `id_from`, MAX(`id`) as `id_to`, COUNT(1) `count_id`
FROM `session`
GROUP BY (FLOOR(IF(id>0, id-1, id) / 10));
```

Please feel free to change the table and column names as per your schema.

Hope this helps.